# How to display contents of mounted /boot and '/' root partitions?

Tags: linux, debian, command-line, mount, debian-installer

How to display contents of mounted `/boot` and `'/'` root partitions of Debian on SSD drive from Linux Live CD?  I know `ls -1` to list directory contents, but what is exact steps to get this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Mounting a HDD

To mount a HDD that's physically connected to your system, you first need to identify the device handle that's been assigned to it. I typically use the command line tools `blkid` or `lsblk` to find out this information.

*blkid*

```
$ sudo blkid
/dev/sda1: UUID="XXXXXX" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda2: UUID="XXXXXX" TYPE="LVM2_member" 
/dev/mapper/fedora_greeneggs-swap: UUID="XXXXXX" TYPE="swap" 
/dev/mapper/fedora_greeneggs-root: UUID="XXXXXX" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/mapper/fedora_greeneggs-home: UUID="XXXXXX" TYPE="ext4"
```

*lsblk*

```
$ lsblk
NAME                      MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                         8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk 
├─sda1                      8:1    0   500M  0 part /boot
└─sda2                      8:2    0 465.3G  0 part 
  ├─fedora_greeneggs-swap 253:0    0   7.7G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
  ├─fedora_greeneggs-root 253:1    0    50G  0 lvm  /
  └─fedora_greeneggs-home 253:2    0 407.6G  0 lvm  /home
sr0                        11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

So we can see from the above that I've got a ext4 partition on `/dev/sda1`, and a LVM partition on `/dev/sda2`. Since you're interested in your `/boot` device, that's typically formatted as a `ext4` partition, so to mount it:

```
$ sudo mount -r /dev/sda1 /mnt
```

And it should be accessible to you under `/mnt` as a read only directory.

#### Mounting an ISO

If on the other hand you'd like to mount an ISO, you can do so, by using the `mount` command, along with the `loop` option.

```
$ sudo mount -o loop <some.iso> <mount point>
```

*Example*

```
$ sudo mount -o loop VBoxGuestAdditions_4.3.10.iso /mnt/
mount: /dev/loop0 is write-protected, mounting read-only
```

And you can now see the ISO's contents:

```
$ ls -l /mnt/
total 57016
dr-xr-xr-x. 2 root root     2048 Mar 26 14:04 32Bit
dr-xr-xr-x. 2 root root     2048 Mar 26 14:04 64Bit
-r-xr-xr-x. 1 root root      647 Oct  8  2013 AUTORUN.INF
-r-xr-xr-x. 1 root root     6966 Mar 26 13:56 autorun.sh
dr-xr-xr-x. 2 root root     2048 Mar 26 14:04 cert
dr-xr-xr-x. 2 root root     2048 Mar 26 14:04 OS2
-r-xr-xr-x. 1 root root     5523 Mar 26 13:56 runasroot.sh
-r-xr-xr-x. 1 root root  9901516 Mar 26 14:01 VBoxLinuxAdditions.run
-r-xr-xr-x. 1 root root 20784640 Mar 26 14:14 VBoxSolarisAdditions.pkg
-r-xr-xr-x. 1 root root 16900432 Mar 26 13:55 VBoxWindowsAdditions-amd64.exe
-r-xr-xr-x. 1 root root   311584 Mar 26 13:46 VBoxWindowsAdditions.exe
-r-xr-xr-x. 1 root root 10463320 Mar 26 13:47 VBoxWindowsAdditions-x86.exe
```

Comment: I tried mount command, bit it says "mount: only root can do that"

Comment: @triwo - Correct, you need to prefix it with `sudo`. I realized I left that out. I added it, sorry about that.

Comment: And unmounting also requires `sudo` prefix?

Comment: @triwo - correct. Only root can mount/unmount.

Answer (score 1):

```
ls /boot
ls /
```

… however you might want to expand upon your question, as Debian / SSD drive / live CD are (more or less) irrelevant to listing directory contents. Maybe you're asking where the boot and root partitions from a live CD are mounted, e.g. [`/mnt/gentoo` and `/mnt/gentoo/boot`](https://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/handbook/handbook-x86.xml?part=1&chap=4#doc_chap6)?.

Comment: Debian on SSD drive not booting, and I want to list contents of these partitions (on SSD drive) using Live CD. How to mount and unmount partitions for this?

Answer (score 0):

If the files you want to look at are in an ISO, mount the ISO in Windows as a Virtual CD.  Once you use the LiveCD as an installer, you cannot view the filesystem as the contents are extracted to RAM or /tmp (still in RAM) and then mounted as `/` and `boot`, thanks to the [SqushFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SquashFS).  Note that viewing the mounted ISO in Windows will show squashfs as a file, although you can't see what is in it.